# How to get text-box counts in javascript

Tags: javascript

H i have a button "Add text" when on-click it creates the text-boxes,now  How can i get the count of text-boxes in JavaScript i create text-boxes like

```
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[1]" id="my_textbox1" />
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[2]" id="my_textbox2" />
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[3]" id="my_textbox3" />
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[4]" id="my_textbox4" />
```

the reason why i need to count is ,i am  fetching values from ajax and creating new text-box appending new text-box like :

```
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[5]" id="my_textbox5" value="seomthing"/>
```

Now I would like to know the number of text-boxes present. It would be best if I can get the count through JavaScript .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get all the elements matching substring of id (https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings). This '[id^="my_textbox"]' syntax means you are selecting all elements with `id` starting with `"my_textbox"` string. The just take the `length` of queried collection and you are done. Please see snippet below:

```js
var textboxCount = document.querySelectorAll('[id^="my_textbox"]').length;
console.log(textboxCount);
```

```html
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[1]" id="my_textbox1" />
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[2]" id="my_textbox2" />
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[3]" id="my_textbox3" />
<input type="text" name="my_textbox[4]" id="my_textbox4" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Give your inputs a classname so you can identify them as a group:

```
  <input class="myInputs" type="text" name="my_textbox[1]" id="my_textbox1" />
```

Then in your javascript select them with `querySelectorAll()` and look at the length of the returned collection:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.myInputs')
var number_of_inputs = inputs.length
```